# How to keep Ubuntu 11.10 and Kate editor w/terminal from changing command line when changing tabs?

Tags: command-line, terminal, ubuntu-11.10, c, kate

I am programming C using Kate editor in Ubuntu 11.10. It works great, but when I change tabs in Kate, the terminal line changes to the file path of the tab I click on.

Normally this is not a big deal (other than annoyingly adding extra text to my terminal) however if I am currently RUNNNING a C program, it obviously will type at the command line, which is not so cool.

```
Example terminal window for my C program (its at a menu):

1) select opt 1
2) select opt 2
```

Enter choice: (here it waits for prompt from user)
Now when I click a tab in Kate, it wants to put in the cd / path of the file in that tab, such as: cd /home/user/os/files

And of course since my terminal was waiting for prompt from user it gets that command.. not good.

Perhaps there is no fix, but maybe someone knows? Obviously I could choose NOT to switch tabs or end program before switching tabs...

> Note: I probably made the mistake of putting this under StackOverflow
>   which is more of a programming area - so though repost here might be
>   best (I am not sure how to link the questions but will paste hyperlink
>   to that post - I dont want to violate any stackoverflow/superuser
>   violations) Suggestions on merging them are welcome or if I should delete one?

[StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658350/how-to-keep-ubuntu-11-10-and-kate-editor-w-terminal-from-changing-command-line-w)

Comment: Kate configuration under `Application > Terminal` *Terminal Settings* has a *Automatically synchronise the terminal with the current document when possible* (this is on Ubuntu 12.10, so your may not have it or be slightly different). Do you have this turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pedro Romano:

Kate configuration under Application > Terminal Terminal Settings has a Automatically synchronise the terminal with the current document when possible (this is on Ubuntu 12.10, so your may not have it or be slightly different). Do you have this turned on? – Pedro Romano Sep 30 at 9:04